# Cappuccino on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cappuccino

I'm a Rails dev, and some of the Cappuccino Rails concepts look damn compelling. Can I develop Cappuccino apps on a Windows (Vista) machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, as [the docs](http://cappuccino.org/learn/tutorials/checking-out.php) say, you just need to also add [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)!

Answer (score 2):

Believe me, I know how frustrating it is to ask "how do I do this on my OS" and somebody says "use a different OS".  As a linux user in a Mac-centric Rails community, I've heard it before.  But you're going to face a lot of challenges with Ruby and/or Rails on Windows.

I think there's a good compromise, though.  Install Ubuntu Linux (free) as another partition on your hard drive.  The Ubuntu install makes it easy to carve out a small piece of your hard drive for itself, whatever size you want.  In fact, every time I get a new laptop with a Windows install I really didn't want, I install Ubuntu on the majority of the drive, but leave Windows on a small chunk.  I paid for the license, might as well keep it.

Once you have Ubuntu installed, Rails work will get a lot easier, and you don't need to give up Windows to do it.  I think the dual-boot option is a good one.

http://www.ubuntu.com has everything you need.

Comment: No problems here suggesting an OS change. I think it's a good discussion.
For Rails development, Windows has been fine. 
I tried a dual boot of Linux and just didn't like it. A lot of the things that were intuitive for me in Windows required looking at forums for Linux. I'm sure Linux is excellent for those who know it well, but for me, it wasn't worth the time.
Forgetting Rails, is there any reason why Cappuccino is better on Mac/Linux over Windows?

Comment: It's much better on Mac, for one because there are a lot of tools (mostly relating to cibs and plists) that won't run on non mac machines. Two, all the core devs use Macs, so if Windows breaks, we tend not to notice for a while.

I'd recommend using a Mac if you can, Linux as the next best alternative, and Windows as a last resort. But we'll at least try to keep it working on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can develop! I personally do it on Windows 7. You just can't compile (at least I can't because I have failed to install Narwhal on Windows). I just use the Starter Template to develop. One more problem is that Windows does not have an Interface Editor, so for that you need to deal it with coding! There are many plugins for ob-j syntax highlighting (Vim, Sublime Text Editor 2). Well the ob-j code is directly compiled on the webpage. Use this only for development purpose, if you want to use the app for production please compile or your code can be stolen easily!